# Windows media player cannot play rtsp and mms stream urls in Session 0 of Win7 and Win Server 2008

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2008, rtsp, wmp, session-0-isolation

In Windows Server 2003, we developed a program. The architecture is: 
(1)There is a Service (called ServA), 
(2)There is a process (called ProcB), it is an override Windows Media Player by implementing some necessary WMP interfaces.
(3)ServA will start up ProcB through CreateProcess to play stream urls. ServA and ProcB are all in Session 0.

In Server 2003, it works well.

Now we are transferring it to Windows Server 2008. In Server 2008, it works normally with http protocol urls (like http: //xx/xx.wmv). For rtsp and mms protocol urls (like rtsp://xx/xx.wmv, mms://xx/xx.asf), it cannot play successfully, and return the error code: 0xC00D11B1, error description: “Windows Media Player encountered a problem while playing the file.”

If we donnot start ServA as a service, but just double clicked to start up it. Then ServA and ProcB are all in Session 1. At this time the rtsp and mms protocol urls can play successfully.

In Win 7, the phenomenon is the same with that in Server 2008. We have checked our display and sound devices, and we can assure there is no problem with them.

You can link this url http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/thread/0317c921-dc9c-4e95-9800-77a34f9f516a for more details.